# XSS Laravel и Angular

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel5, angular5

Для защиты от XSS в Laravel используются двойные скобки `{{ $name }}`. Для защиты от XSS в Angular **тоже** исполюзуются двойные скобки `{{interpolationText}}`.

Вопрос - на каком из двух вышеуказанных фреймворков лучше защищаться от XSS? Нужно ли очищать переменную в Laravel, а затем (уже очищенные) данные передавать в Angular? Или же нужно отправлять "небезопасные" данные, не проверяя их в Laravel, а в Angular их уже очищать? Какая практика лучше? Стоит ли "очищать" данные и в Laravel и в Angular одновременно, или же это бесполезная трата ресурсов (очистить сначала на сервере, потом Angular на клиенте)?

Спасибо. Надеюсь понятно объяснил..

Comment: Пишешь фронт на современном фреймворке - не заморачивайся по `blade` шаблонизатору.
хорошей практикой будет очистка данных перед сохранением в базу на сервере, а также перед выводом на клиенте (если не требуется выводить динамический html)

Comment: @МаксимК я правильно понял, что при сохранении данных в бд я через Laravel очищаю данные. А клиенту отправляю данные без очистки с серверной стороны, при этом очищаю полученные данные через Angular. Верно?

Comment: Да, на бэке очищаешь перед сохранением в БД. При показе данных на клиенте сам решаешь, что надо показать. Если это простая строка - экранируй на клиенте. Если динамический html - выводишь на клиенте как есть. Именно там, где необходимо вывести html от клиента - пристальное внимание и пристальная обработка перед сохранением в бд.